# Table not modified since date

Tags: sql

I have a table with following fields.
Part ID, Quantity, Last modified date

I am using the following simple query to retrieve data, how can I add more criteria to show that quantity in hand 0 and part did not modified since 01/01/2015 till now.

```
SELECT *
FROM table001
where quantity_on_hand=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another filter in your WHERE clause like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM table001
WHERE quantity_on_hand=0
AND ModificationDate <= '20150101' -- Date format = 'YYYYMMDD'
```

Comment: I personally think that this answer is less straight forward because of using  `Date format` but that's just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you're looking for

```
SELECT * FROM table001 WHERE quantity_on_hand = 0 AND last_modified_date <= '2015-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to combine multiple conditions you could use [`AND`,`OR` operators](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) after `WHERE` clause.

Here I think you might be looking for:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table001 
WHERE 
    qunatity_on_hand=0 AND last_modified_date <= '2015-01-01';
```